# How long until a song shows up on the Musicbrainz XML/JSON service?

Tags: musicbrainz

I just added a release that wasn't on musicbrainz before:

http://musicbrainz.org/release-group/8f6f6155-20dd-4960-9381-47805e6b50f5

Here's my query for that song that's returning 0 results:

http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording/?query=recording:%22When%22%20AND%20artist:%22Life+On+Planet+9%22%20AND%20dur:[268473%20TO%20293473]%20AND%20number:6%20AND%20release:%22Bittersweet
%22&limit=1&fmt=json

and the actual song:

http://musicbrainz.org/recording/78c84a0c-8b79-46ff-af4d-653ce52540ca

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that while the changes to the database show up instantly, the indexing for search for the XML service takes at least a day, maybe less than that.

Either way, the results showed up the next day.